# Cryptography club

Tags: cipher, story

You have been invited to join a secret cryptography society, but you have to decode this message and meet at the location.

This is the email you receive:

---

Let's learn your times tables!

$5$ X 8 = 74
2 X $3$ =$ $12
2$5$ X 1$0$7 = 2794
41$ $X $46$ =$ $279
3$52$ X$ $75 = $55$6
65$ $X $5$ = 9$3$1
$52$8546$ $ X $17$ = 382799$6$
94$ $X $32$6 = $78$
57$ $X $4$0$4$ =$ $1234567890
$32$0 X$ $753 = $49$467
494$ $X $46$ =$ $573
$56$ X$ $367 = $56$
683$ $X $52$85 =$ $748
$53$4 X$ $749 = $176$
7552$ $X 73$32$ =$ $278

Now you've learnt your times tables, it's time to$87$

Pbzr naq svaq hf!

---

Where are you supposed to meet?

Hint:

> You need to go into edit mode to see it

Other hint:

> Why isn’t everything encrypted with mathjax?

Comment: Not every digit in your expressions is encoded as MathJax; perhaps this has to do with the answer.

Comment: hmmm... maybe   :)

Comment: Why are those two lines in bold? can someone edit it to make it normal text?

Comment: They are in heading font; heading font shows in bold.

Comment: Placing a row of dashes directly below a single-line text marks it as heading, which will be rendered as bold type. If you want to draw a horizontal line, type a line of dashes with blank lines before and after it.

Comment: Awwwww you weren’t supposed to SAY that...

Comment: Well, I wanted to give you the chance to edit your own post as you see fit. I didn't know whether you wanted the horizontal lines or not. (And given that there seems to be some markup thingy afoot, who knows what I would have broken?)

Comment: I did it on purpose to try and get you to look at the raw text

Comment: Is the inconsistent formatting of spaces before or after $X$ relevant? And the lack of a space in $to84$?

Comment: It was all meant to be like that, some of it is goes nowhere, but some of it does...

Comment: Is anyone even trying to solve this riddle?

Comment: Umm, I don't think this even counts as a riddle @RohitJose :D

Comment: I'm not sure if it does as well, but I thought I'd do something different for a change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to meet at...

> The Training Room at 52.4754° N, 1.8845° W

The message was...

> Hidden by encoding certain characters with mathjax.  These numbers converted from ascii to text yielded the address above.  I assumed that the final 84 was actually an 87.

Comment: I thought I put in the co ordinates for the custard factory... but you're close enough. Well done!